# CSS Selector - Match text relative in table

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to match am having the following table from the following [PAGE](https://edikte.justiz.gv.at/edikte/ex/exedi3.nsf/0/19dd135274ceb842c12586390028507e?OpenDocument&f=1&bm=2)

I would like to get `Liegenschaftsadresse:`, `Grundstücksgröße:` and `Schätzwert:`.

As this table changes from page to page I would like to match the above texts with css selectors and pick the values that are next to it.

For example I would like to get the red underlined field:

[image]

Any suggestions how to match this with css-selectors?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Do you want to read text that is inside of some CSS selectors?

Comment: @StepUp Yes basically I would like to read `Schätzwert` and get the text that is next to it.

Comment: CSS can’t select text, and it can’t select parent elements from the child. This will - I think - require javascript, but if you post your “*[mcve]*” code (posting a link to your code doesn’t remove the requirement to post your minimal representative code in your question) there may be some css options.